# Plot solutions to a trigonometric equation on the unit circle

Tags: plotting

For example, when solving the equation
$$\sin(13x)+\sin(9x)=\cos(2x)$$
(by hand) you get the solutions
$$
x=
\begin{cases}
\pm\tfrac{\pi}{4}+\pi n,\\
\tfrac{\pi}{66}+\tfrac{2}{11}\pi n,\\
\tfrac{5\pi}{66}+\tfrac{2}{11}\pi n,
\end{cases}
\qquad n\in\mathbb{Z}.
$$

I can make a graphic illustration of the solutions with the following (primitive) code;

```
Clear[x1, x2, x3, x4, n]
x1[n_] := \[Pi]/66 + 2/11 \[Pi] n
x2[n_] := 5 \[Pi]/66 + 2/11 \[Pi] n
x3[n_] := -\[Pi]/4 + \[Pi] n
x4[n_] := \[Pi]/4 + \[Pi] n
p1 = Table[{Cos[x1[n]], Sin[x1[n]]}, {n, 0, 10}];
p2 = Table[{Cos[x2[n]], Sin[x2[n]]}, {n, 0, 10}];
p3 = Table[{Cos[x3[n]], Sin[x3[n]]}, {n, 0, 1}];
p4 = Table[{Cos[x4[n]], Sin[x4[n]]}, {n, 0, 1}];
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Point[p1], Point[p2], Point[p3], Point[p4]}]
```

but is there a smarter/more efficient way to make the plot (and perhaps with a little more ‘fancy’ output)? TIA.

Answer (score 7):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = Sin[13 x] + Sin[9 x] == Cos[2 x];

FunctionPeriod[#, x] & /@ (List @@ eqn)

(* {2 π, π} *)

x /. (sol = SortBy[Solve[{eqn, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x] // FullSimplify, N])

(* {π/66, (5 π)/66, (13 π)/66, π/4, (17 π)/66, (
 25 π)/66, (29 π)/66, (37 π)/66, (41 π)/66, (49 π)/66, (
 3 π)/4, (53 π)/66, (61 π)/66, (65 π)/66, (73 π)/66, (
 7 π)/6, (5 π)/4, (85 π)/66, (89 π)/66, (97 π)/66, (
 101 π)/66, (109 π)/66, (113 π)/66, (7 π)/4, (11 π)/6, (
 125 π)/66} *)
```

Much faster:

```
x /. (sol2 = 
   NSolve[{eqn, 0 <= x <= 2 Pi}, x] /.
    r_Real :> Pi*RootApproximant[r/Pi])

(* {π/66, (5 π)/66, (13 π)/66, π/4, (17 π)/66, (
 25 π)/66, (29 π)/66, (37 π)/66, (41 π)/66, (49 π)/66, (
 3 π)/4, (53 π)/66, (61 π)/66, (65 π)/66, (73 π)/66, (
 7 π)/6, (5 π)/4, (85 π)/66, (89 π)/66, (97 π)/66, (
 101 π)/66, (109 π)/66, (113 π)/66, (7 π)/4, (11 π)/6, (
 125 π)/66} *)

% === %%

(* True *)
```

Plotting,

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotStyle -> LightGray,
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}], x] /. sol}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eqn], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{x, Cos[2 x]}], {x, Cos[2 x]}] /. sol},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Subtract @@ eqn], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Tooltip[Point[{x, 0}], x] /. sol},
 PlotLabel -> Style[Subtract @@ eqn, 14, Black]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps this?:

```
SolveValues[Sin[13 x] + Sin[9 x] == Cos[2 x], x] /. C[1] -> 0 // 
  Exp[I #] & // ComplexListPlot
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice! Can I add the unit circle too? I tried a `Circle` command but it did not work as expected.

Comment: @mf67 `Show[<plot>, Graphics[{Circle[]}]]` is one way.  Also `ComplexListPlot[SolveValues[...] /. C[1] -> 0 // Exp[I #] &, Prolog -> {Circle[]}]`

Comment: @mf67 `ListPolarPlot[ Values@Solve[Sin[13 x] + Sin[9 x] == Cos[2 x], x] /. C[1] -> 0 // PadRight[#, {Automatic, 2}, 1] &, Prolog -> {Circle[]}]` is another way.

Comment: Michael E2, OK! I thought `Circle[{0,0},1]` would work, but it didn't. It seems the argument should be empty. (I don't understand why though.)

Comment: @mf67 `Circle[{0, 0}, 1]` works, too, in both my example codes. It must be how you added it to the code.

Comment: Yes, it worked now. I must have made a mistake earlier.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**

```
ParametricPlot[{Cos[x], Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {Sin[13 #3] + Sin[9 #3] - Cos[2 #3] &}, 
 MeshStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Red}]
```

[image]

**Original**

```
sol = NSolve[Sin[13 x] + Sin[9 x] == Cos[2 x] && 0 <= x <= 2 π, x,
   Reals]
Graphics[{Circle[], {PointSize[Medium], Red, 
   Point[AngleVector /@ (x /. sol)]}}]
```

[image]